# (S)CSS define global color

Tags: css

So I would like to define a global color in my Angular project in the `styles.scss` stylesheet.
I know I can defined global variables like this

```
:root {
  --blueish: #658bc7;
}
```

and then in other styles(heets) reference to it

```
p {
  color: var(--blueish);
}
```

But this is **NOT** a globally defined color. This is a globally defined variable.
We could for example do

```
p {
  color: aliceblue;
}
```

and this does work since `aliceblue` is globally defined along with a lot more preset colors. Is there a way for me to ADD a color to this list using (S)CSS? If not, would it be possible in less or SASS?

Comment: *this is NOT a globally defined color. This is a globally defined variable* --> it's very subjective here. Both are the same for me. the difference between `var(--aliceblue)` or `aliceblue` is the syntax

Comment: If that is the case, then let me rephrase it. How can I call the syntax <p style=color: blueish;> lorem ipsum </p>

Comment: I think you are trying to redefine colors in css like trying to redefine the keyword `static` in js. You just gotta use the syntax workaround

Answer (score 2):

**You Can Define and Assign Variables in scss/sass Like This**

```scss
$blueish: #658bc7;
p {
  color: $blueish;
}
```

### Notice that in sass/scss files named "blablabla" are globally scope
while files named "_blablabla" are not globally scoped and must be imported by.

You Must Have one globally file in sass/scss for example named "style.scss" that imports all scss/sass files in it for example:

```scss
/*
  This File is only for imports
*/
@import "./libraries/_variables.scss";
@import "./libraries/_mixins.scss";
@import "./layouts/_header.scss";
@import "./pages/_about.scss";
```

**Also, you can not add "_" and ".scss" in the importing it is not necessary for your editor will understand it for Example :**

```scss
@import "./libraries/variables";
@import "./libraries/mixins.scss";
@import "./layouts/_header";
```

**They are the same as the above example!**

Answer (score 2):

You can assign in SCSS vars with $varName. Important note if you like to use dash or underScore in your varnames. For the SASS compiler, $var-name is the same as $var_name. You have to take that into consideration.

**SCSS**

```
$blueish: #658bc7;
p {
  color: $blueish;
}
```

Will compile to **CSS**:

```css
p {
  color: #658bc7;
}
```

Comment: The problem is that this is not globally defined in terms of the Angular framework. This will not work in stylesheets outside of the root `styles.scss` file. And since you say this is compile time logic, It will also not work in inline styles such as `<p style=color: $blueish;> lorem ipsum </p>`

Comment: Inlinestyles dont will work on this way. To your problem with global sytles.scss. Are you able to include you  scss style file to it?